# How to include Open Source license in GitHub SBOM export?

Tags: github

Is there a way to include the Open Source license in the GitHub SBOM export? If not is there a way to easily generate a list of dependencies that includes the name, version, and open source license for a GitHub repo?

I tried the Export SBOM under dependencies but this does not seem to include the Open Source license for the dependencies.